# QR-Code reader windows library

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, qr-code

I would like to know if there's any library (like zbar for android) for reading QR-Codes in windows store apps? I already know ZXing.Net, but that only decodes from an image, I would like to decode it directly from the camera.

Thanks for your help :)

**Edit:** Is there a source code for a demo application? That would be even better since I'm a beginner with windows store apps.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Optical Reader Library of Nokia: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Optical_Reader_Library_for_Windows_Phone_8

And if it doesn't solve your problem, or you simply don't like it, it is relatively easy to make your own one using ZXing.NET and camera reader task.

Comment: It gives me this error when installing the nuget package:
"Could not install package 'NokiaImagingSDK 1.0.272.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Comment: When creating a new project, try to select a .NET framework version other than 4.5, although I am not sure, the nuget package might be not compatible with the version 4.5.